# Check equaling enum without parameter

Tags: haxe

I use enums but can't find good way to check eqauling.

```
enum Turn {
    A(value:Int);
    B(value:Int);
}
class Test {
    static function main() {
        var turn = Turn.A(100);
        //I want to Check turn is Turn.A(any value) without using 'switch'.
        if (turn == Turn.A) ...
    }
}
```

Is there any good and simple way to checking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`.match()` function](https://api.haxe.org/EnumValue.html#match):

```
if (turn.match(Turn.A(_)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't tested this, but it might be faster using Type class:

```
if (Type.enumConstructor(turn) == "A") ...
```

Because it is unsafe ("A" could be a typo), I suggest to use ExprTools:

```
import haxe.macro.ExprTools.*;
if (Type.enumConstructor(turn) == toString(macro A)) ...
```

There is another way, but I don't think it is faster :

```
if (Type.enumIndex(turn) == Type.enumIndex(A(0))) ...
```

And you might get condition evaluated to true for different enums:

```
enum Color { Red; }
if (Type.enumIndex(turn) == Type.enumIndex(Red)) ... // true
```

Comment: Using reflection instead of properly typed code seems like a terrible idea... If anything that's _slower_, `.match()` gets optimized to a simple integer comparison: https://try.haxe.org/#90CE2 - `if(Test.turn[1] == 0)`

Comment: Type != Reflection, e.g. Dynamic is not used, EnumValue->String is a function signature

Comment: The API docs disagree with you there, `Type` is considered reflection: https://i.imgur.com/11z2XWY.png Also, you already pointed out various type safety issues yourself. ;)

Comment: That's bad. For example, enumConstructor could simply return arrayOfConstructorNames[enumIndex(enum)]. One of the reasons why I'm not into Haxe anymore (just visiting). Still, hope it helps newcomers better understand Haxe